# Problems with bash path when using 'su'

Tags: ubuntu, bash, path, bashrc, su

In Ubuntu *Lucid Lynx*, I'm trying to do

```
su -l user -c "foo.sh args"
```

where `foo.sh` is an executable bash script on the `PATH` set in `~user/.bashrc`.  Unfortunately, this fails because it can't find `foo.sh`.  If I `su -l user` and manually type `foo.sh args` at the command line, it works fine.  The PATH augmentation is done in `~user/.bashrc` and appears to work whether or not I `su` with `-l` interactively, but it doesn't appear to work when I specify the command.

Any idea why this is, and how I can get around that?

Answer (score 2):

It's starting the shell as a non-interactive login shell so it processes `~/.profile` and not `~/.bashrc`. You can set your `PATH` in that file or do it in a common file that both of them source. Some people/distributions set one startup file to source the other one, but I don't recommend this.

From `man bash`:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a  non-interactive  shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes com‐
>          mands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.   After  reading
>          that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
>          in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one  that
>          exists  and  is  readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the
>          shell is started to inhibit this behavior.